# Notify all clients of added student and update ui

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a blazor web assembly project and a signal r service project I would like to invoke the changes to the ui when I add a student.
Currently I have to refesh the page to see the addition.

StudentService.cs

```cs
public class StudentService
{
    public HubConnection connection;

    public StudentServicen()
    {    
        connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()                                            
                     .WithUrl(".../StudentsHub")
                     .Build();

        connection.StartAsync();
    }

    public async Task<List<Students>> GetAllStudents() => 
    await connection.InvokeAsync<List<Students>>("GetAllStudents"));    

    public async Task<Boolean> AddStudent(StudentData student) => 
    await connection.InvokeAsync<Boolean>("AddStudent", student);

}
```

Students.razor

```
@inject StudentService StudentService

<ul >

    @foreach (var student in students)
    {
       <li>@student.Name</li>
    } 

</ul>

@code {  

private List<Students> students = new List<Students>();  

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    students = await StudentService.GetAllStudents();        
}
```

Students hub in another project.

```cs
public class StudentsHub : Hub
{
    public Task<List<Students>> GetAllStudents() => 
    Task.FromResult(getAllStudents.GetAll());

    public Boolean AddStudent(StudentData student) => 
    studentService.AddStudent(student);
}
```

Comment: You say that with this implementation you need to refresh the page in order to call ```getAllStudents```?

Comment: Yes I want it to show the updated student details from getAllStudents.GetAll(). The Students.razor is a component that shows all of the students details.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You've provided partial code snippets, so I created a small sample which is working, and using a custom service to access the server hub, and return values to a razor component into which the custom service is injected.

Note that when you use services and call backs you must use the InvokeAsync method, which dispatches to Blazor's SynchronizationContext, an object that enforces a single logical thread of execution.

Here's the complete code, copy and test it, and see if it can help you with your app...

### UserService.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client;

namespace BlazorSignalRApp.Client
{
    public class UserService
   {
        public event Action Notify;
        public string User { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        HubConnection hubConnection;

        public UserService(NavigationManager navigationManager) 
        {
             hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl(navigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("/chatHub"))
            .Build();

             hubConnection.On<string, string>("ReceiveMessage", (user, 
                                                               message) =>
             {
                User = user;
                Message = message;

                if (Notify != null)
                {
                   Notify?.Invoke();
                }
             });

              hubConnection.StartAsync();
              hubConnection.SendAsync("SendMessage", null, null);
      }

      public void Send(string userInput, string messageInput) => 
          hubConnection.SendAsync("SendMessage", userInput, messageInput);

      public bool IsConnected => hubConnection.State == 
                                             HubConnectionState.Connected;
   }
}
```

### Index.razor

```
@page "/"

@inject UserService UserService
@implements IDisposable

<div>
    <label for="userInput">User:</label>
    <input id="userInput" @bind="@userInput" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="messageInput">Message:</label>
    <input id="messageInput" @bind="@messageInput" />
</div>
<button @onclick="@(() => UserService.Send(userInput, messageInput))" 
             disabled="@(!UserService.IsConnected)">Send Message</button>

<hr />

<ul id="messagesList">
    @foreach (var message in messages)
    {
        <li>@message</li>
    }
</ul>

@code {

    List<string> messages = new List<string>();
    string userInput;
    string messageInput;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        UserService.Notify += OnNotify;

    }

    public void OnNotify()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserService.User))
        {
            var encodedMsg = UserService.User + " says " + 
                                                        UserService.Message;
            messages.Add(encodedMsg);
        }

        InvokeAsync(() =>
        {
            StateHasChanged();
        });
    }


    public void Dispose()
    {
        UserService.Notify -= OnNotify;
    }

}
```

### ChatHub.cs (Put this file in a Hubs folder in the Server project)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;

namespace BlazorSignalRApp.Server.Hubs
{
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
        {
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
        }
    }
}
```

### Program.cs (Client project)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

namespace BlazorSignalRApp.Client
{
   public class Program
   {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);

            builder.Services.AddSingleton<UserService>();

            builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");

            await builder.Build().RunAsync();
        }
   }
 }
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Hi @enet, this is a great example. I'm wondering if you consider this the best way to update clients when the model changes, or if there is another better practice out there? My concern with SignalR is you have to maintain a large number of sockets on the server and this can get costly to maintain with large scale apps.